# MongoDB randomly select documents but in order of an enum

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, mongodb-query

I want my query to randomly select 3 entries, but it should always select all entries with status (which is an enum) "NEW" first, then "IN_PROGRESS", then "PAUSED". How can I achieve this?

So far I have the following code, which does not consider the order of the status enum yet:

```kotlin
mongoTemplate
        .aggregate<Book, Book>(
          newAggregation(
            match(
              where(status).`in`(BookStatus.allToBeRead),
            ),
            sample(3),  
          ),
        )
```

```kotlin
enum class BookStatus {
    NEW,
    IN_PROGRESS,
    PAUSED,
    DONE,
    DISMISSED,
;

    companion object {
        val allToBeRead = listOf(
            NEW,
            IN_PROGRESS,
            PAUSED
        )
    }
}
```

Some examples for better understanding:

**Example 1**

**Source Data**

book1(status=IN_PROGRESS)

book2(status=PAUSED)

book3(status=NEW)

book4(status=NEW)

book5(status=NEW)

book6(status=NEW)

**Result**

book4(status=NEW)

book5(status=NEW)

book3(status=NEW)

**Example 2**

**Source Data**

book1(status=IN_PROGRESS)

book2(status=PAUSED)

book3(status=NEW)

book4(status=NEW)

**Result**

book4(status=NEW)

book3(status=NEW)

book1(status=IN_PROGRESS)

Comment: You are asking filtering, aggregation and sorting questions all in one go - these are all different concepts.  I cannot follow what you want to achieve.  Perhaps list in a table your source data and what you want as a result.  Also what Mongo access framework are you using?

Comment: @AndrewL I rephrased my question and hope it's more understandable now. I use Spring Boot for accessing MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go...

```
enum class Status { NEW, IN_PROGRESS, PAUSED }
data class Book(val name: String, val status: Status)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    findRandom(listOf(
        Book("book1", Status.IN_PROGRESS),
        Book("book2", Status.PAUSED),
        Book("book3", Status.NEW),
        Book("book4", Status.NEW),
        Book("book5", Status.NEW),
        Book("book6", Status.NEW),
    ))
    println()
    findRandom(listOf(
        Book("book1", Status.IN_PROGRESS),
        Book("book2", Status.PAUSED),
        Book("book3", Status.NEW),
        Book("book4", Status.NEW),
    ))
}

fun findRandom(books: Collection<Book>) {
    val answer= mutableListOf<Book>()
    answer.addAll(books.filter { it.status==Status.NEW }.take(3))
    answer.addAll(books.filter { it.status==Status.IN_PROGRESS }.take(3 - answer.size))
    answer.addAll(books.filter { it.status==Status.PAUSED }.take(3 - answer.size))
    answer.forEach { println(it) }
}
```

produces

```
Book(name=book3, status=NEW)
Book(name=book4, status=NEW)
Book(name=book5, status=NEW)

Book(name=book3, status=NEW)
Book(name=book4, status=NEW)
Book(name=book1, status=IN_PROGRESS)
```

To achieve the random requirement you should retrieve all the data from Mongo into a `List` and then execute the `List.shuffle()` method on it, then retrieve the data from the list.